# How to auto receive calls programatically in android versions above kitkat

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to develop an app which auto receive calls from particular numbers.
Like i can add the numbers that i want to auto receive. I did a lot of research and found similar questions but none of them worked. Some codes did work but only upto kitkat version and code did not work on versions above kitkat. I want the code that support all android versions. Its very important for me so please answer quickly. I really need your help.
I want the app to work in background so also please help me and write the code to implement this in a background service.

I was successful to run the app on versions upto kitkat but above kitkat the code does not work.

Comment: AFAIK it will not be possible because it seems like a privacy concern. I think you might get some workaround in rooted phones.

Answer (score 0):

Android very specifically does NOT allow this, because doing so is an opening to a lot of telephone scams involving reversed charges.  They've actually never allowed it, but people found hacks on old versions to get around that.  Every time Google finds one of these, they shut it down in the next version.  So there is no reliable way to do it, and if you find a way expect it to disappear shortly afterwards.

Comment: Actually I will not publish it in play store only me and my brother will use it. I want when I call him his phone automatically receive my call on whatever android version he has

Comment: That's fine-  there's still no method of doing it that works across all versions.  Maybe with a rooted phone you could do something with faking keypresses/touches, but that would be it.